# GCP: Does a regional disk's writes replicate across zones before an OS fsync?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fsync

> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repds
>
> Regional persistent disks **provide synchronous replication** for
> workloads that might not have application-level replication.

If the VM crashes after disk writes but before an `fsync`, is that data lost?

When is a disk write replicated to the replica disk in another zone?

Note: The VM OS is the default Ubuntu, with the default file system.

Comment: The exact answer depends on how you (the application) have writes setup (write-through or write-behind). Typically, Linux caches writes in memory and periodically flushes the cache to disk (fsync is one way). Anything stored in memory will be lost. In otherwords, the answer depends on how the application is designed. Some apps cache data in the application's memory, then write to the OS, which then writes to disk. Each of these steps are asynchronous and subject to data loss.

Comment: My understanding is there are 3 locations for data: (A. Persisted on disk, B. In OS buffers, C. In application memory before the write fn call). Question is, does regional disk replication happen for the state in step A, or step B? I guess step A, but there is no documentation and my understanding is limited

Comment: Once data is written to disk, it is replicated by Google. Your question is when do the applications and OS write to disk. This link might help you: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/high-availability-regional-persistent-disk

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley that link is useful

Answer (score 1):

Data that are written to the [regional persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repds) are replicated to another zone.

**Answering your question - after the `fsync`.**

**Whatever remains in OS or your application buffer is not replicated** - hence in the event of an zonal outage this data will be lost so [you have to put that into cosderation when you design you application](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/high-availability-regional-persistent-disk#design_considerations).

Quoting @John Hanley:

> The exact answer depends on how you (the application) have writes
> setup (write-through or write-behind). Typically, Linux caches writes
> in memory and periodically flushes the cache to disk (fsync is one
> way)